# How do I get everything in my title box and center the Title (resources)

Tags: html, css

I'm setting up a title box with html + css. I'd like everything to be within the border of the title box, except the Title (Resources) How do I do that?

I'd like the title (Resources) to interrupt the top border, I'd like that to be centered and have some padding on the left and right side.

Here's my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/huskydawgs/0zfwf2dk/50/

```css
    .resources-box {
      padding: 8px;
      background-color: #e2e3e4;
      width: 100%;
      padding: 20px 0;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    .column-resources-box {
      width: 193px;
      float: left;
      margin: 15px;
      font-size: 0.9em;
    }
    .column-resources-box img {
      border: 1px solid #2251a4;
    }
    h4 {
      font-family: Georgia, Helvetica, Arial;
      font-size: 1.1em;
      font-weight: normal;
      margin: 1em 0 .6em 0;
    }
    h4.resources-bar a {
      font-family: Georgia;
      font-size: 11px !important;
      color: #ffffff !important;
      background-color: #2251a4;
      padding-top: 4px;
      padding-bottom: 4px;
      text-align: center;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      display: block;
    }
    h4.resources-bar a:hover {
      background-color: #f66511;
      color: #fff !important;
    }
    .title_box {
      border: #f66511 1px dotted;
      padding: 0 5px;
    }
    .title_box #summary {
      position: relative;
      top: -0.5em;
      margin-left: 1em;
      display: inline;
      background-color: white;
      color: #2251a4;
      font-family: SegoeBold, Helvetica, Arial;
      font-size: 26px;
      line-height: 34px;
      margin: 0 0 10px 0;
      text-align: center;
    }
    .title_box #content {}
```

```html
<div class="title_box" id="resoruces">
  <div id="summary">Resources</div>
  <div class="column-resources-box">
    <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple">
      <img alt="Apples" height="73" src="http://www.hapadesign.com/images/apples.jpg" width="193" />
    </a>
    <h4 class="resources-bar">
            <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple">WEBINAR</a></h4>
    <p align="center"><strong><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple">Apples</a></strong>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="column-resources-box">
    <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banana">
      <img alt="Bananas" height="73" src="http://www.hapadesign.com/images/bananas.jpg" width="193" />
    </a>
    <h4 class="resources-bar">
            <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banana">WEBINAR</a></h4>
    <p align="center"><strong><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banana">Bananas</a></strong>
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="column-resources-box">
    <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orange">
      <img alt="Orange" height="73" src="http://www.hapadesign.com/images/Oranges.jpg" width="193" />
    </a>
    <h4 class="resources-bar">
            <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orange">WEBINAR</a></h4>
    <p align="center"><strong><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orange">Orange</a></strong>
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="column-resources-box">
    <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pineapple">
      <img alt="Pineapple" height="73" src="http://www.hapadesign.com/images/Pineapples.jpg" width="193" />
    </a>
    <h4 class="resources-bar">
            <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pineapple">WEBINAR</a></h4>
    <p align="center"><strong><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pineapple">Pineapple</a></strong>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: here you're the fixed version http://jsfiddle.net/0zfwf2dk/53/

Comment: I want the Resources to be part of the border. So the Resources title would break up the border, but would be centered.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a `clear` property to clear `left` `float` you have applied to `.column-resources-box`.

```
.clear { 
  clear: left;
}
```

```css
}
.resources-box {
  padding: 8px;
  background-color: #e2e3e4;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.column-resources-box {
  width: 193px;
  float: left;
  margin: 15px;
  font-size: 0.9em;
}
.column-resources-box img {
  border: 1px solid #2251a4;
}
h4 {
  font-family: Georgia, Helvetica, Arial;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin: 1em 0 .6em 0;
}
h4.resources-bar a {
  font-family: Georgia;
  font-size: 11px !important;
  color: #ffffff !important;
  background-color: #2251a4;
  padding-top: 4px;
  padding-bottom: 4px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: block;
}
h4.resources-bar a:hover {
  background-color: #f66511;
  color: #fff !important;
}
.title_box {
  border: #f66511 1px dotted;
  padding: 0 5px;
}
.title_box #summary {
  position: relative;
  top: -0.5em;
  margin-left: 1em;
  color: #2251a4;
  font-family: SegoeBold, Helvetica, Arial;
  font-size: 26px;
  line-height: 34px;
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}
#summary .summary_content {
  background-color: white;
  display: inline-block;
}
.title_box #content {}
.clear {
  clear: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="title_box" id="resoruces">
  <div id="summary">
    <div class="summary_content">Resources</div>
  </div>
  <div class="column-resources-box">
    <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple">
      <img alt="Apples" height="73" src="http://www.hapadesign.com/images/apples.jpg" width="193" />
    </a>

    <h4 class="resources-bar">
            <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple">WEBINAR</a></h4>

    <p align="center"><strong><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple">Apples</a></strong>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="column-resources-box">
    <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banana">
      <img alt="Bananas" height="73" src="http://www.hapadesign.com/images/bananas.jpg" width="193" />
    </a>

    <h4 class="resources-bar">
            <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banana">WEBINAR</a></h4>

    <p align="center"><strong><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banana">Bananas</a></strong>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="column-resources-box">
    <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orange">
      <img alt="Orange" height="73" src="http://www.hapadesign.com/images/Oranges.jpg" width="193" />
    </a>

    <h4 class="resources-bar">
            <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orange">WEBINAR</a></h4>

    <p align="center"><strong><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orange">Orange</a></strong>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="column-resources-box">
    <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pineapple">
      <img alt="Pineapple" height="73" src="http://www.hapadesign.com/images/Pineapples.jpg" width="193" />
    </a>

    <h4 class="resources-bar">
            <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pineapple">WEBINAR</a></h4>

    <p align="center"><strong><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pineapple">Pineapple</a></strong>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

> What are float and clear for?
>
> If you look in a typical magazine you’ll see images illustrating the
>   articles, with the text flowing around them. The float property in CSS
>   was created to allow this style of layout on web pages. Floating an
>   image—or any other element for that matter—pushes it to one side and
>   lets the text flow on the other side. Clearing a floated element means
>   pushing it down, if necessary, to prevent it from appearing next to
>   the float. Although floating was intended for use with any elements,
>   designers most commmonly use it to achieve multi-column layouts
>   without having to abuse table markup.

Reference: [w3.org - Floats and clearing](http://www.w3.org/wiki/Floats_and_clearing) - [CSS-Tricks - What is "Float"?](http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you want. Is this close?

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/0zfwf2dk/54/)

I moved the content out of the `div class="title_box"`, and modified the css

```
<div class="title_box" id="resoruces">
    <div id="summary">Resources</div>
</div>

.title_box #summary { 
    background-color: white; 
    color: #2251a4;
    font-family: SegoeBold,Helvetica,Arial;
    font-size: 26px;
    line-height: 34px;
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: No, I'd like everything to be within the border of the title box, except the Title (Resources) 

I'd like the title (Resources) to interrupt the top border, I'd like that to be centered and have some padding on the left and right side.